# Border draw as like underline of Title

Tags: html, css, border

I have use the following code snippet to draw the border

```
 <div style="height: 250px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid #99999A;">
        <div style="padding: 0.7em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;height: 30px;border-bottom:1px solid #99999a;">
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have create the Fiddle to explain my working scenorio from the following link

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/pk9cG/)

From this i got the out as like below screen shot:

Screen shot:

[image]

How to modify this by change the border bottom style of inner div to get output as like below screen shot

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You keep asking quesions and you accept no answer... Please have a look at the help to see how SO works.

Comment: @Raja What you actually try to achieve at SO? A new record of unaccepted answers...?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pk9cG/1/)

```
<div style="height: 250px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid #99999A;">
<div style="padding: 0.7em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;height: 30px;border-bottom:1px solid #99999a; width:90%; margin:0 auto;">Title</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of padding, use margin for inner div. Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/DZNbP/

```
<div style="height: 250px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid #99999A;">
        <div style="margin: 0.7em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;height: 30px;border-bottom:1px solid #99999a;">
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this cod**e

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main">
        <div class="conmain">
            <h1>Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Css**

```
.main{
    height: 250px;width: 300px;border: 1px solid #99999A;

}
.conmain{ 
    padding: 0.7em 0.4em 0.2em 0.4em;
}
.conmain h1{border-bottom:1px solid #99999a; line-height:30px;margin:0; font-size:12px;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pk9cG/3/)**